# How to re-enable Azure Postgresql Database User after too many failed login attempts

Tags: postgresql, azure, cloud

After a password rotation for an [Azure Postgresql Single Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/) user this error showed up in my Java application:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: authentication failed for user "<username>": too many failed login attempts`

How to re-enable this Database User?

**EDIT:**
It seems time-sensitive, after waiting ~10 minutes the problem seems solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems time sensitive, after waiting ~10 minutes the problem is solved!

Two observations to help other people:

- It's probably also IP related, as from other IP addresses the same user could connect perfectly fine (with the correct pwd :) ).
- At the same time a different user (which was also rotated) was able to login from the same K8s cluster (same IP)